# How to run BitcoinCash node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, bitcoin-cash

How to install and Launch Bitcoin Cash daemon on machine?

I have already synchronized full BitCoin node, Here is the link [bitcoin.org](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1604) from here i learn how to setup BTC node

I also want to run BitcoinCash node but i do't have any idea about BCH node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to [BitcoinCash's site](https://www.bitcoincash.org/), you can see there are multiple implementations of the bitcoincash protocol.
You can select any one, say BitcoinABC.
On their page you can find source code as well as binaries for your type of system which you can download and run.